# about running an firewall on aws cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, firewall, cloud, iso

i am a firewall developer and i am new to the cloud. Finally, I've made an iso file of my firewall running on centos. I want to test its operability in a cloud environment. So, I want to use this firewall in front of a virtual machine that I will be installing on cloud. I am thinking of using AWS. How can I achieve this, which services should I use and is it possible to use that iso image as a firewall in front of my web server in the cloud? Can I arrange network interfaces as I wish (layer2 interfaces, layer3 interfaces, bonding etc.? Could someone provide me information about how to get it done? Is it possible, if so, how it is so?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To migrate a VM into AWS you use the poorly name "[application migration service](https://aws.amazon.com/application-migration-service/)" to import your VM.

Generally in cloud you should use cloud native features where possible rather than deploying instances with software. AWS provides Security Groups (free), NACLs (free), AWS Network Firewall (somewhat expensive).